# How can I pass an additional parameter to Jquery autocomplete in addition to "q" param

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, handler

I have used jquery autocomplete 1.1 version.

I have to get list of shops for a particular circle.

For this I have drop down list and a textbox.

Drop down list has the list of circles ,

I need to pass this "cid"  as the additional parameter to the asp.net Handler
where i can retrieve this "cid" and query the data base based on the
text  entered the the "cid".

any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: -1 since there is no code where there clearly should be code.

Comment: Please express yourself very very clearly, so that the users can respond to your query

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback function for the [autocomplete's `source` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-source). So, all you need to do is set up a callback function that does an AJAX call itself to get the possible matches:

```
source: function(request, response) {
    var cid = 'your cid value from where ever you get it';
    $.ajax({
        // Whatever AJAX options you need go here
        url: '/some/place',
        data: { q: request.term, cid: cid },
        success: function(data) {
            response(data.split('\n'));
        }
    });
}
```

The current search term is inside `request.term` inside the callback. Once you have the expanded list of possible matches, call the `response` function to hand it back to the autocomplete widget. For illustrative purposes I'm assuming that your server returns the matches as a list of newline separated matches, you might have to do something a little different with your real data.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer.I have solve the situation by passing an additional parameter in query string .

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution by passing cid as the querystring.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        var cid = $("#ctl00_cphMain_hdnCid").val();
        $("#ctl00_cphMain_txtSearch").focus();
        $("#ctl00_cphMain_txtSearch").autocomplete("AutoCompleteHandler.ashx?cid=" + cid + "&storetype=1", { autoFill: false });
    });
```

In the autocompletehandler.ashx I have retrieved the "cid"
like below:

```
int cid = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["cid"].ToString().Trim());
```

and used this as parameter for `SqlCommand`  object